# "+=" operator and int long usage

Tags: java

```
int a = 1L;
```

This doesn't compile (of course).
*incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int*

```
int b = 0;
b += Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

This does compile!

But why is it allowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `+=` that's a compound statement and Compiler internally casts it. Where as in first case the compiler straight way shouted at you since it is a direct statement :)

The line

```
b += Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

Compiler version of it equivalent of

```
b += (int)Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

of course there will be  lossy conversion from conversion of long to int.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Comment: ah i c, didn't found it in the spec myself. Well a warning of the compiler/IDE would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the compiler is smarter than you think. At compile time itself, it will replace the actual value of the expression `b+=Long.MAX_VALUE` by `-1`. So, `Long.MAX_VALUE` is converted to an `int` and assigned to the int field at compile time itself)

Byte code :

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: iconst_0
         1: istore_1
         2: iinc          1, -1 // Here
         5: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
        line 5: 2
        line 6: 5
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       6     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
            2       4     1     b   I
```

Comment: hm currently i am thinking the compiler is too "smart" here